# Locking post with "off topic comments" lock causes wrong message to be displayed

Tags: bug, locked-posts

I [locked an answer that received a high number of off topic comments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25064745/16587), however the message that is displayed is the wrong message:

> This question exists because it has historical significance, but it is not considered a good, on-topic question for this site, so please do not use it as evidence that you can ask similar questions here. This question and its answers are frozen and cannot be changed. More info: help center.

Screenshot: [image]

Comment: Are you sure you didn't just click the wrong thing? [Worked fine for me.](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/25065032/revisions)